# Django: Creating a Reference Code for each new order

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

For my E-commerce project, I am trying to generate a reference code that can be understandable yet unique at the same time:

I am trying to generate a reference code that after each purchase is made that includes that day, month, year, hour, minute and a digit that increases with a new transaction

DDMMYYHHMMXXX
Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute,3 digits starting with 001 and increasing with each new order.

How do I do it?

My current code generated is:

```
def create_ref_code():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=6))
```

model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is how far I have reached but I am not sure how to increase the count with every new order

```
def create_ref_code():
    now = datetime.now()
    code = now.strftime("%y%m%d%H%M%S")
    print(code)
    count = + 1
    digit = str(count).zfill(3)
    my_code = (code, digit)
    return ''.join(my_code)
```

Answer (score 2):

for that you can extend the save method and retrieve all the order count and also you can use something like this to pad the leading zeroes on that count

```
str(1).zfill(3)
```

this will create 001 output in string and you need this in string format to concat the data so no need to convert that to integer again

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        count = ***retrieve you count of that orders using query*** + 1
        digit = str(count).zfill(3)
        self.reference_code = your logic to create reference code
```

**updated:**
you don't have to increment count like that

```
def create_ref_code():
    now = datetime.now()
    """
    'make query to count all todays order here'
    count = Order.objects.filter(filter argument by date).count() + 1
    """
    code = now.strftime("%y%m%d%H%M%S")
    digit = str(count).zfill(3)
    my_code = (code, digit)
    return ''.join(my_code)
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, I am trying to integrate your answer to it but I couldn't

Comment: I understood now what you are trying to reach but is there a way to just increase the count for the `digit` every time `create_ref_code` is generated

Comment: Sorry i don't know any way to increase btw according to your problem you also have to reset that at the end of the day too.

Comment: instead of getting them to reset can I get the `digit` to increase by 1 every time `create_ref_code` is called or run. For example initially it is 000, 1st time it is called to become 001 and so on ?

Comment: it that is the case then the only thing you can do is extend save method  and then use the id as the count and the good thing is it will never repeated, unique and auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

instead of DDMMYYHHMMXXX try UUID-4

code :

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4()
```